# How to copy a sub directory to a root directory using grunt-contrib-copy?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

My structure is like below. I want to copy assets folder from app directory to dist directory?

```
app
   assets
      imgs
      css
      fonts
   index.html
dist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the current working directory to *app*. Select all subdirs and files of *assets*. Set the destination to *dest*.

```
grunt.initConfig({
    copy: {
        dist: {
            cwd: 'app',
            src: ['assets/**/*'],
            dest: 'dist/',
            expand: true
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['copy:dist']);
```